# case statement in SSIS result Column name based of values available in each row

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I need to write a case statement in SSIS for which I have to populate the column name based of values available in each row.

I have got some idea from few post here but I am stuck how to populate Column name as result, I don't want to hard code name unless there is no other way.

```
Assetname |SP Rating|InHouse |Moody  |RatingCounter
-----------------------------------------------
ABC       |         |  A+    | AB    |
------------------------------------------------
XYZ       | B+      | A+     | AA+   |
------------------------------------------------
PQR       | BBB     |        | B+    |
------------------------------------------------
MNC       |         |        |       |  
-------------------------------------------------
IIR       |         | AAA+   |       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I have two requirement first part I have done, but I am not sure how to do the next part.
If its been SQL I would have progressed further but I am not great in SSIS.

### Requirement 1

Populate the Rating Counter with a count how many rating available for each asset
Solution :-  I have written this logic in a Derived column to count non null value and add them

```
!ISNULL([Moody]) ? 1 : 0) + (!ISNULL([SP Rating]) ? 1 : 0) +(!ISNULL([InHouse]) ? 1 : 0)
```

Is there any other better way to do this?

### Requirement 2

This is bit complex. I need to add another derived column 'Rating Source'
and populate it based on Rating Counter.

- Case Rating COunter = 0 : then Blank
- Case Rating COunter = 1 : then the column header of the provider 
  (e.g. for last Row IIR Rating Source would be 'In House')
- Case rating counter = 2 in case 2 rating are available take the worse rating
  (e.g. 1st row for asset ABC rating source would be Moody (as AB is worse than A+) or for 3rd for asset PQR the rating source be populate with 'SP rating' as BBB is worse then B+
- case Rating counter = 3
  When 3 rating available then take the mid rating for example for 2nd row XYZ AA+ is best, A+ is mid and B+ is worse we have to pick the column header for A+ which is 'InHouse'

I am not sure how would I do this in SSIS. Any pointer would be grateful

Comment: Your approach for requirement 1 is fine. 2 though. 2 is tricky because of your last business rule. Generally what you're looking at is an Unpivot operation (make your wide table into a tall table) and then something like an Aggregate would have satisfied 0/1/2 (although you'd have needed to provide a mapping to ensure B+ is sorted properly over BBB). Maybe a Conditional Split and then a script component for rating counter 3.

Comment: Requirement 2 is complex enough that I would just immediately go with a script transformation.